# Is there a way to avoid FieldAccessException?

Tags: .net, reflection.emit

We have a class library that does some basic operations similar to an ORM, basically we can do something like this:

```
conn.Query<EntityType>("select * from table");
```

and get back a `List<EntityType>`. Since the mapping from column names to properties on the entity type is stored inside the entity type, we can easily construct basic objects when we need to with only a subset of the properties.

The problem is, this code relies heavily on reflection, and we just discovered that the overhead, which we knew we had, was far bigger than what we anticipated.

example timings of various operations related to a "select * from table":

1. IDataReader, loop through all the rows, 178ms
2. IDataReader, call GetValues to get the object[] array, for all rows, 260ms
3. IDataReader, call GetValues, construct new object and add to list, for all rows, 356ms
4. IDataReader, call GetValues, construct new object, **use reflection to copy values to properties**, ~10.500ms (**29x step 3**.)

We cache the reflection involved, but still there's too much overhead.

Since 99% of the objects involved are simple properties with (1 or 2 backing fields), I thought I could just generate the following code through IL/DynamicMethod:

```
instance._Id = (int)value;
```

This fails with `FieldAccessException`, and I assume this is because the fields are private. Is there any way for me to generate this code at all, or am I just barking up the wrong tree security-wise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; in your `DynamicMethod` you need to tell it to associate itself with `EntityType`; then the access problem goes away. Use the overload that sets `owner` to `typeof(EntityType)`, and `skipVisibility` to `true`.

However, in most cases you should be able to go the the properties virtually as  quickly as the fields. So prefer the properties unless there is a good reason to choose fields. Of course, if using attributes you can let the user decide, by decorating the most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the property read/write and call the "set property" method instead of trying to write directly to the backing property?

This also has the advantage that if the implementing class used auto generated properties (eg **string Name{get;set;}** then your code-gen solution will still work as it doesn't make any assumptions about how the property is implemented.

Comment: I'm creating dynamic methods now that will use the property, but the entity objects are generated so we can easily add attributes telling the reflection generator for these that it can safely access the fields, for extra performance. Since well over 90% of our application is bound by database traffic in terms of performance, we're now focusing on trying to minimize the overhead in this area.